# Для чего здесь обрезается строка?

Tags: c#

*Только не ругайтесь, пожалуйста. Я изучаю чужой код и некоторые моменты не понимаю.*

```
public class PathToBaseDirectory : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string currentDirectory = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory;
            if (currentDirectory.EndsWith("\\bin\\Debug"))
            {
                int index = currentDirectory.IndexOf("\\bin\\Debug");
                currentDirectory = currentDirectory.Substring(0, index);
            }
            return currentDirectory + value.ToString();
        }
        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
```

Мне не особо понятны следующие строки :

```
 int index = currentDirectory.IndexOf("\\bin\\Debug");
                currentDirectory = currentDirectory.Substring(0, index);
```

Обязательно ли это в своих проектах прописывать? что вообще происходит?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего это какой-то костыль для запуска приложения из-под студии.

Обычно все, что нужно приложению, лежит в папке с результатами компиляции. В студии это обычно `bin\Debug` в папке проекта. Скорее всего тот, чей код вы изучаете, или не знал как скопировать дополнительный контент (через Copy to output directory в свойствах), или решил это не делать по каким-то своим причинам.

Поэтому под отладкой у вас приложение пытается выпрыгнуть в папку проекта и поискать файлы контента там (через обрезание `bin\Debug`). В релизе, скорее всего, файлы контента копировались к бинарникам вручную.

---

Нет, в своих проектах такое прописывать необязательно. Это костыль для какой-то местной ситуации. Правильно - помечать проектные файлы контента/данных, с которыми вам нужно работать, флагом Copy to output directory = true.

Comment: Потом прописывается в главной форме :`<local:PathToBaseDirectory x:Key="imagePath"></local:PathToBaseDirectory>`
Наверное, у автора возникли проблемы с выводом изображения

Answer (score 0):

Вообще, это написано криво. В данном случае обрезается `\bin\Debug` в конце.

```
if (currentDirectory.EndsWith("\\bin\\Debug")) // Если текущая директория - дебаг
{
    int index = currentDirectory.IndexOf("\\bin\\Debug"); // найди индекс старта
    currentDirectory = currentDirectory.Substring(0, index); // возьми строку с начала до этого индекса
}
```

Вполне достаточно было бы написать

```
const string endsWith = @"\bin\Debug";
if (currentDirectory.EndsWith(endsWith))
{
    currentDirectory = currentDirectory.Substring(0, currentDirectory.Length - endsWith.Length);
}
```

Еще по-хорошему следует добавить `#if DEBUG`, ибо, скорее всего, это должно использоваться только под дебагом.